# Smack : Remove check server capability requests (disco#info)

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I have noticed that smack sends **disco#info** request for some of the service i.e **muclight** and **pubsub**. Smack send these request before the auth callback triggers in my connection manager. I don’t want to send these disco#info requests as we always communicate with the same server and its capabilities are known to us. As we implement services on the client side knowing this is supported by the server.

```
<iq to='muclight.server.com' from='id@server.com/R' id='yN82u-18' type='get'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'></query></iq>

iq to='pubsub.serve.com' from='id@server/R' id='yN82u-20' type='get'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'></query></iq>

<iq to='upload.server.com' from='id@server/R' id='yN82u-24' type='get'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'></query></iq>

<iq to='vjud.server.com' from='id@server/R' id='yN82u-22' type='get'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'></query></iq>
```

These are some of the noticed discon#info request.

Please guide how can I avoid these disco#info requests.